# Not able to resolve the following error from my code. Can someone explain?

Tags: php, localhost, web-development-server

> Fatal error: Uncaught InvalidArgumentException: Invalid token format
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\src\Google\Client.php:449
>   Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\GoogleLogin\g-callback.php(5):
>   Google_Client->setAccessToken(Array) #1 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\GoogleLogin\GoogleAPI\src\Google\Client.php on line
>   449

This is my code snippet:

```
<?php
    require_once "config.php";

    if(isset($_SESSION['access_token']))
        $gClient->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    elseif(isset($_GET['code'])){
        $token = $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $token;
    } else {
        header('Location: login.php');
        exit();
    }


    $oAuth = new Google_Service_Oauth2($gClient);
    $userData = $oAuth->userinfo_v2_me->get();


    $_SESSION['id'] = $userData['id'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $userData['email'];
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $userData['gender'];
    $_SESSION['picture'] = $userData['picture'];
    $_SESSION['familyName'] = $userData['familyName'];
    $_SESSION['givenName'] = $userData['givenName'];

    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if `$_SESSION['access_token']` is empty, null or false. You're checking to see if it exists,and it obviously must, but that doesn't mean it has a valid value.